# Google cloud platform oauth window problem

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform

I tried to create an oauth client google cloud platforms showed me this message

[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9cTj.png)

I published oauth window

[published window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buvfd.png)

but the error did not disappear

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54hj5.png)

please tell me what to do to activate oauth client ID,thanks

Answer (score 0):

The shared notification is just an informational warning and seems to be reproducible in the console by creating a credential.